# Want to use jQuery .nextUntill but exclude a div inbetween

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to jQuery so please excuse me!

I have a PHP function that returns me a blog from a MySQL database; it returns headline, subtitle and content.

```
$result = getData();  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                extract($row);
                ?>
                    <div class="headline"><?php echo $headline ?></div>
                    <div class="subtitle"><?php echo $subTitle ?></div>
                    <div class="content"><?php echo $content ?></div>
                    <?php
            }
```

There are three entries shown so far. I have a jQuery that hides the content and expands it when the headline is clicked using the nextUntill method and .slideToggle on the content.

```
    $(".content").hide();

$(".headline").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(".headline").slideToggle(500);  
});
```

my problem is that slideToggle is executed on every div until the next headline, which includes the subtitle. So when the headline is clicked the content is shown but the headline disappears.

I cannot just select content to slide as it will slide all three of the content divs will then show.

Is there a way to exclude the subtitle inbetween the headline and content?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, you want to hide the next `.content` element. If that's right, you can get the first element matching that selector from the set of following siblings:

```
$(this).nextAll(".content").eq(0).slideToggle(500);
```

Or, to do it as you suggest, you can use `not`:

```
$(this).nextUntil(".headline").not(".subtitle").slideToggle(500);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BspqF/) of the first version.

Comment: Yes this works great, I like the fact you can select a div class by its index. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i am giving guess, as i understood question in this way, so you can try `not` Selector  [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(this).nextUntil(".headline").not(".subtitle").slideToggle(500);
```